# Finding prime factors of a number

Tags: c#, algorithm, primes, factors

Okay, so just having a little fun I thought I'd see if I could write an algorithm to find all of the prime factors of a number. The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var subject = long.MaxValue;
        var factors = new List<long>();
        var maxFactor = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Factoring {0} ...", subject);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        while (subject > 1)
        {
            var nextFactor = 2;
            if (subject % nextFactor > 0)
            {
                nextFactor = 3;
                do
                {
                    if (subject % nextFactor == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    nextFactor += 2;
                } while (nextFactor < subject);
            }

            subject /= nextFactor;
            factors.Add(nextFactor);
            if (nextFactor > maxFactor)
            {
                maxFactor = nextFactor;
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();

        var factorAnswer = 1L;
        factors.ForEach(f => factorAnswer *= f);

        Console.WriteLine("Factors: {0} = {1}",
            string.Join(" * ",
                factors.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()),
            factorAnswer);
        Console.WriteLine("Max Factor: {0}", maxFactor);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

and its output is:

```
Factoring 9223372036854775807 ...
Factors: 7 * 7 * 73 * 127 * 337 * 92737 * 649657 = 9223372036854775807
Max Factor: 649657
Elapsed Time: 3ms
```

It works, and IMO awfully fast, but it's a little brute force. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 12):

**Other algorithms**

Wikipedia has an article which lists other [Factoring algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms).

---

**Your algorithm**

Re. your algorithm, I see you're checking all odd numbers, which includes non-prime numbers such as 9.

Your sieve would be faster if you only checked prime numbers, for example by using a list like [this one](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt) or [this one](http://www.bigprimes.net/).

Furthermore you're checking all the way to subject. Your last time through the loop would be faster if you give up as soon as nextFactor > sqrt(subject).

---

**Your C# code**

As for your C# code:

- What type is `nextFactor` when you declare it as `var nextFactor = 2;`? I fear that it might be `int` not `long`.
- Your code might be very slightly faster if you used the `Capacity` property of `List`.
- There's something very strange (and slow) about your loop: after you find a nextFactor value such as 7, then you begin your search from 2 again! You code would be faster if you moved your `long nextFactor = 2;` initialization to do it only once, before/outside the `while` loop, and changed your `nextFactor = 3;` statement to `nextFactor += (nextFactor == 2) ? 1 : 2;`. You could then also eliminate your `maxFactor` variable, because the largest factor value would be left/stored in `nextValue` after you exit the `while` loop.
- It might be better to use [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) instead of `long` (because `long.MaxValue` is only about 10^18, whereas some people want to factorize larger numbers than that).

Comment: What do you mean by that `Capacity` remark? I don't see how would it help here.

Comment: Just that `factors.Add` might be ever-so-slightly slower if List has to reallocate internal memory instead of having enough Capacity from the moment it's constructed?

Comment: And how do you know how much `Capacity` is enough? Or do you mean to always assume the worst (and for example unnecessarily allocate large list if the number is a prime)? In any case, this doesn't matter here, as long as the list is less than hundreds of elements or so.

Comment: @svick I'm guessing that List.Add is the single most expensive statement in the loop; and that setting a sensibly large Capacity once [would be faster than allowing it to grow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762817/default-capacity-of-list).

Comment: For the example 2^63-1, that Add was executed 7 times, while nextFactor += 2 something like 300 000 times. I think the Add won't measurably affect the overall performance.

Comment: @svick I don't think it's very important either; I'm just trying to be thorough. The behaviour would be different if the `subject` were exactly 2^62 ... Add would be executed 62 times and might dominate the performance.

Comment: For 32-bit integers there really isn't anything much faster than just brute-forcing all primes under 65536. For 64-bit integers you might gain some performance by doing a quick sieve for these factors and then using Fermat's or Pollard's p - 1 to weed out the larger ones. Up to 256-300 bits the Rho algorithm (cycle finding) is probably optimal. After that you should pull out the big guns with ECM, QS, NFS, ... and eventually you are screwed because there is no known polynomial-time general purpose factoring algorithm. But implementing these is a great exercise!

Answer (score 9):

## Code

Your code seems fine.

Like [@ChrisW](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/40573/7773) highlighted, take care about types. Your variables `nextFactor` and `maxFactor` are actually integers.

Also, `string.Join` can take objects - it will call ToString() internally. You can convert `string.Join(" * ", factors.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray())` to `string.Join(" * ", factors)`

## Algorithm

I suggest 2 improvements to the algorithm.

### You are re-iterating values that you already discarded as not being factors.

If 2 is not a factor of `subject` on the first iteration, it will never be. So when you find a new factor X, on the next iteration you can continue looking for factors from X upwards - instead of re-checking the already-discarded values [2..X].

### You only need to check until `nextFactor*nextFactor>subject`

And then the last factor is actually `subject` itself. :)
Right now, you check until `nextFactor==subject` (thus next iteration `subject==1`).

#### Explanation:

if subject is e.g. 21 and nextFactor is 11... since no number smaller than 11 is a factor, then all its factors are bigger or equal to 11.

- If subject has **one** factor, that factor must be the `subject` itself (21);
- If it has more than one, and because its factors are at least as big as 11, then `21>=X*Y`, `X>=11`, and `Y>=11`.
  (X being the next factor, and Y being the next subject.)

So, in the case where `nextFactor*nextFactor > subject`, you know that the last factor has to be subject itself, and you can terminate processing earlier.

Comment: Beware of overflow with `nextFactor*nextFactor > subject`; consider a safer alternative (like the C++ `greater_than_sqrt()` function in [Find perfect and amicable numbers](/q/286696/75307)).